# Scope of Web Development

Tags: language-agnostic

This is a bit different topic and i donot want to start long thread for that reason I am seeking help that what should you people suggest me to do

I have knowledge of 
HTML/CSS
Javascript
ASP.Net
C#desktop apps
a bit ab PHP

so where do i switch in to php side or dot net side. and eventually after mastering that technology i will be looking for some freelancing work so in short where should i spend my efforts to result good earning

*Note: Sorry for starting descriptive topic but i just wanted to have some professional advice.*

Comment: I think that since you already have knowledge of C# and ASP.NET I would stick with that. .Net is a robust solution. Then work on learning MVC. Furthmore, it is good to know as many languages as you need to get the job done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Determine which market is more lucrative where you reside. If there are a lot of .NET shops you might get some ASP.NET work, if there are more PHP shops then that is your best bet. I would go to a job site like careerbuilder or monster and do a search on both in your area and let the numbers lead you.

There is a lot to be said for both technologies and I don't know if either is better than the other. I'm personally mainly a .NET developer but have PHP experience. I'll use whatever gets the job done...

Answer (score 3):

I would stick with open source technologies if you're freelancing. Often people who hire freelancers don't want to pay for software licenses and so .Net might be less useful for you.

The bottom line:

I guess we can talk about all of this theoretically, but realistically figure out where your contracts will be coming from and which skills you are best fit to promote. You'll soon have a direction that is assured to be profitable.

Comment: What license fee are you talking about?

Comment: Depending on which technology is used for development and deployment licensing fees may need to be paid. This is often the case when working with technologies associated with Microsoft.

Comment: The only "fees" associated with deploying a .net solution is a cost for a web server OS.  Which is trivial with respect to how much it costs to develop software; and completely non-sensical if you are talking about a hosted app as hosting costs are at parity.

Comment: I guess we can talk about all of this theoretically, but realistically figure out where your contracts will be coming from and which skills you are best fit to promote. You'll soon have a direction that is assured to be profitable.

Comment: @Bnjmn: update your answer with that last comment.  It's perfect.

Comment: @Chris Lively glad we can agree, I've made the changes as you've pointed out.